# ARM board booting issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, porting, u-boot

I am porting the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) to a [TI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments) ([AM335x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitara_ARM_Processor#The_Sitara_family) SK) board. But while booting the board, it is not loading fully. It stops as shown below.

```
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3126496 Bytes = 3 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   XIP Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

What is the root cause for this?

Answer (score 4):

The boot of Linux on embedded is done in 3 steps:

1. Bootloader

   - Low-level hardware initialization
   - Loads the Linux kernel in RAM and passes control to Linux
2. Bootstrap loader (inside the Linux kernel image):

   - Decompress and relocate the kernel
   - Pass control to it
3. Linux kernel:

   - Boot the system by running start_kernel() which, in the end, spawns the *init* process

Your output is between step 2 and step 3 (i.e., kernel decompressed).

You've probably not set all the things to have a working console:

1. Compile the target Linux kernel enabling through *make menuconfig* the serial console in

   ```
   Device Drivers -> Character Devices -> Serial Drivers
   ```
2. Enable the specific driver for serial communications in the kernel configuration (i.e., through *make menuconfig*)
3. Set Linux console on the right device by setting option **console=device,baudrate** in the **bootargs** variable of U-Boot.

Comment: That is identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811948/arm-linux-start-kernel-is-not-calling-after-decompressing-uimage/19830656#19830656) for another question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are connected with a serial console to the device, as you see the [U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) output. Have you configured your kernel to use the serial console? If not, you probably will not see anything.

Show us the kernel command line, plus what did you do (to/in the kernel)? Are you using a plain vanilla kernel?

Assuming you have a kernel for your device that supports your boards hardware, you can for example add something like the following to the kernel command line: `console=ttyS0,115200`.

That way, the kernel will use that console for output. But for that to work the kernel has to be built for your device (e.g., has to know where and that there is a serial device).

That being said, it can be that the kernel is just booting up, but you don't see anything, because the kernel does not know the serial console you are using is existing and thus is not displaying anything.

Comment: Another important pitfall to consider is that the exact device name for the serial device may differ between older and newer kernel versions or between certain configurations. For example I had a board that would have console on ttyS2 in the OS install that came with it which gave no output on my self compiled kernel. The reason was that the same serial port was named ttyO2. This was an OMAP, but it may be close enough to be the same issue.

Comment: @ortang iam using following boot commands => "mmc rescan 0
fatload mmc 0 81000000 uImage
fatload mmc 0 82000000 ramdisk.gz
setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 mem=256M root=/dev/ram rw initrd=0x82000000,16MB ramdisk_size=65536 earlyprintk=serial
bootm 81000000 - 80000000"

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a kernel problem, because the bootloader loaded the Linux image and then the kernel started, but it hang up.

Probably the kernel has a problem with initialization of some hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of kernel image flashed on the NAND flash memory, say from 3 MB to 6 MB.

I have seen this kind of issues happening due to kernel size issues. Paste the output of the size of kernel
with:

```
ls -alh uImage
```

And check if this more than 3 MB. If so, you have got to change your kernel flash write command to a better value.