# ARM LINUX ":start_kernel is not calling after decompressing uImage"

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, porting, archlinux, u-boot

The start_kernel() function is not calling after decompressing the kernel image (uImage) on an ARM board:

Why is the start_kernel() function is not calling? I know it should call from file *arch/arm/kernel/head.s*.

What are sequences happening after decompressing uImage and calling start_kernel()?

Comment: You have not provided any evidence to support the question.

Comment: You need to state: CPU/Soc model, kernel version, boot loader version, and toolchain version. If you are using an OTS board rather than your own custom board, then state the board model.

Comment: @Jonathan Ben-Avraham ..I am using AM335X TI board.

Comment: Please add the console output from power up until hang so that we can see what U-Boot is doing. Also, stop the boot at the U-Boot prompt and do `printenv` and put the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of boot stopping after "Uncompressing Linux… Ok, booting the kernel" is that the console device in your kernel command line is not correct. For example, after upgrading from 2.6.35 to 3.19.5, the console device name could have changed from `/dev/ttyAM0` to `/dev/ttyAMA0` (on the i.MX23/28). You should also check that the serial port settings, if there are any, following the console device name in the kernel command line are correct.

Check that you are passing a valid ATAG array or device tree (*.dtb) file via your boot loader.

Another possible cause is incorrect entry point.

Try search engine phrase "ARM boot hangs after 'Uncompressing Linux....done, booting the kernel'"

Answer (score 0):

The boot of Linux on embedded is done in 3 steps:

1. Bootloader

   - Low-level hardware initialization
   - Loads the Linux kernel in RAM and passes control to Linux
2. Bootstrap loader (inside the Linux kernel image):

   - Decompress and relocate the kernel
   - Pass control to it
3. Linux kernel:

   - Boot the system by running start_kernel() which, in the end, spawns the *init* process

Your output is between step 2 and step 3 (i.e., kernel decompressed).

You've probably not set all the things to have a working console:

1. Compile the target Linux kernel enabling through *make menuconfig* the serial console in

   ```
   Device Drivers -> Character Devices -> Serial Drivers
   ```
2. Enable the specific driver for serial communications in the kernel configuration (i.e., through *make menuconfig*)
3. Set Linux console on the right device by setting option **console=device,baudrate** in the **bootargs** variable of U-Boot.

Comment: That is identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786857/arm-board-booting-issue/19807301#19807301) for another question.